# PowerBI - Data Transformation (Data filtering)

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I am new to powerBi reporing. I have a situaion where one of the column has multiple texts seperated by the semicolan. I want to extract only text which has specific name and create new columns with that text and remaining texts can be deleted

Example : Column A has these values and want to extrac only this column has "fallout"
as a text in this column

ABCDEFfallout;CD_FD,RK_GEFD;Team_Arion;Netsfallout;123ABC;20141310_release

So expecting output as two new columns with value of ABCDEFfallout, Netsfallout for that row.

This is not a one time data transform activity, it shoube happened anytime I refresh data from snowflake.

Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You want the result as *columns*? I suggest you take an intro course to Power BI to understand the tool, what it is used for, and how to build data models - what you are describing sounds very strange.

Comment: Can you provide a sample table and expected output.

Comment: Before tranforming :                                                                                                                     
Column A : Sample 1
Column B  : ABCDEFfallout;CD_FD, on_off;Netsfallout;20141310_release        
Expecting row : 
Column A : Sample 1
Column C (New) : ABCDEFfallout
Column D (New) : Netsfallout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this in M / PowerQuery

```
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Custom", each List.RemoveNulls(List.Transform(Text.Split([Column1],";"), each if Text.Contains(_,"fallout") then _ else null))),
ExpandColumnNames=List.Transform({1 .. List.Max(List.Transform(#"Added Custom"[Custom], each List.Count(_)))}, each "FoundColumn"&Text.From(_)),
#"tranform" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Custom",{{"Custom", each Text.Combine(_,"|"), type text}}),
#"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(tranform, "Custom", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("|", QuoteStyle.Csv), ExpandColumnNames)
in #"Split Column by Delimiter"
```

[image]